# How to make this bootstrap nav submenu always open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code to make bs nav, but I don't understand how to make submenu always open without clicking menu name.

This is the code:

[http://jsfiddle.net/6hrmodok/2/](http://%20jsfiddle.net/6hrmodok/2/)

and please answer this question with the new code.

Comment: Which one? You can always give it a unique class for future editing.

Comment: the menu open1 and open2.
i want that menu always open @AdamAzad

Comment: "New Tesla"... now, you aren't a new Tesla. Tesla could read and write on at least 2 languages.

Answer (score 1):

To make the submenu always open in bootstrap navbar, you just need to add a class "open" like this `<li class="dropdown open">` this will make your bootstrap's navbar submenu always open and it will toggle also.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gw-nav-list>li.always-active>a, 
.gw-nav-list>li.always-active>a:hover, 
.gw-nav-list>li.always-active>a:focus, 
.gw-nav-list>li.always-active>a:active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2574A9;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.gw-nav-list>li.always-active:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid #2574A9;
    border-width: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.always-active .gw-submenu,
.gw-nav-list>li.always-active .gw-submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

And for JavaScript;

```
$('.gw-nav > li:not(.always-active) > a').click(function () { 
     ....
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hrmodok/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you can open the submenu on page load with simple jquery code as below in your script file.

```
var pageload = function()
{
     $(".gw-nav > li").each(function () 
   { 

      var checkElement = $(this);
      var ulDom = checkElement.find('.gw-submenu')[0];

        if (ulDom != undefined) {
            checkElement.addClass('active');
            checkElement.find('ul').slideDown(300);
            return;
        }

   });

}();
```

check the fiddler here.

http://jsfiddle.net/o1jw4txg/